# How to get refresh token from google calendar using js

Tags: javascript

Hi all I have following code

```
   const handleSync = () => {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
      console.log('loaded client');

      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        scope: SCOPES,
      });

      gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', () => console.log('bam!'));

      gapi.auth2
        .getAuthInstance()
        .signIn()
        .then(() => {
          var events = bb;

          var makeRequest = resource => {
            console.log(resource);
            var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
              calendarId: 'primary',
              resource: resource,
            });

            request.execute(resp => {
              console.log(resp);
            });
          };

          for (var j = 0; j < events.length; j++) {
            makeRequest(events[j]);
          }
        });
    });
    };
```

This code is helps me to add all events in my google account. but every time  when I want to add new one google wanted auth from me, to avoid that I want to take `access_token`. Now In preview I can see all necessary information [photo](https://ibb.co/wsKs23s).

Please help me to figure out how can I gat that information in my code. I need to store that `access_token` in localStorage

Comment: Title: _"How to get refresh token from google calendar using js"_, Body: _"Please help me to figure out how can I gat that information in my code. I need to store that access_token in localStorage"_ - The title should summarize the problem which is then described in the body of the question in more details...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I already resolved that

```
    .then(e => {
          const googleAccessToken = e.vc.access_token;
          localStorage.setItem('googleAccessToken', googleAccessToken);

          var events = bb;

          var makeRequest = resource => {
            console.log(resource);
      ...
    })
```